# Angular2 final version: Injected Service method under unit test returning undefined

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, jasmine, spyon

I am trying to write some unit-tests on a component that got some services injected into it, to load the data from server. Data is loaded in this component on OnInit() method. I am trying that service method returns some dummy data, using spyOn. Following is unit-test setup -

```
let comp: MyComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
let staticDataService: any;
let spy: jasmine.Spy;
let allCountries: string[];

describe('MyComponent', () => {
beforeEach( async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports : [ FormsModule, HttpModule ],
        declarations : [MyComponent],
        providers: [ StaticDataService ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    staticDataService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(StaticDataService);
    allCountries = [] = ["US", "UK"];
    spy = spyOn(staticDataService, 'getCountries').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(allCountries));
    });
it('Countries should be set', () => {
    expect(comp.allCountries).toEqual(allCountries);
    }); 
});
```

Following is the component class that I am unit-testing -

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'myeditor',
  templateUrl: 'my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  allCountries: string[];
  constructor(private _staticDataServices: StaticDataService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDataFromServer();
  }

  getDataFromServer()
  {
    this.allCountries = this._staticDataServices.getCountries();
  }
```

I am getting the following error -

```
    Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 7 0.0.0) MyComponent Countries should be set FAILED
    [1]     Expected undefined to equal [ 'US', 'UK' ].
```

Under the same unit-tests few other tests are working fine, that are not dependent on injected services. Getting 'undefined' while testing the properties that are set by services. 
Can someone please help what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to call `fixture.detectChanges()` for the `ngOnInit` to be called.

   ```
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
   fixture.detectChanges();
   ```
2. `getCountries` returns a `Promise` so you need to `then` it, otherwise the value of `allCountries` will just be promise and not the data

   ```
   getDataFromServer() {
     this._staticDataServices.getCountries().then(data => {
       this.countries = data;
     });
   }
   ```
3. Since the promise is asynchronous, you need to use `async` and wait for the asynchronous task to complete by calling `fixture.whenStable()`

   ```
   import { async } from '@angular/core/testing';

   it('...', async(() => {
     fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
       expect(comp.allCountries).toEqual(allCountries);
     })
   })
   ```

---

### UDPATE

Without seeing the `StaticDataService`, I'm guessing you are trying to inject `Http` into it. This wont work in a test environment without further configuration. What I suggest you do is just make the service a mock

```
staticDataService = {
  getCountries: jasmine.createSpy('getCountries').and.returnValue(...);
}

providers: [
  { provide: StaticDataService, useValue: staticDataService }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I apply these changes I am getting the following error -

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I apply these changes I get the following error - 
[1]     TypeError: this._staticDataService.getCountries(...).subscribe is not a function

Not sure why this method is getting called when it should be overridden by the method/values specified in spyOn.

Comment: You can't call `subscribe` on a promise (which is what the mock is returning). That is only for observables. They are different things. You need to call `then` on a promise. If you want to emit an observable instead in your mock, then `and.returnValue(Observable.of(allCountries))`

Comment: You will need to import `rxjs/add/observable/of`

Comment: Thanks, that helps. It passed thru OnInit method. 
Further need to resolve some html parsing errors appearing in same tests..